# SharePoint 2010 Note Board - Notes appearing only by user permission levels

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

My issue is users can only see comments from others within their permission level.  For example, UserA and UserC have Contribute access and can only see each other comments.  However they cannot see UserB's comments whom has full-control and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run full crawl and compare the results.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d51d0563-f3f1-4db6-a1bf-b3dd94f861c6/sharepoint-social-computing-quotnote-boardquot-posts-not-visible-to-other-users?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious